# Perl thread in a loop

Tags: multithreading, perl

I have the following program where I call `TestMe()`. Depending on return code of `TestMe()`, I need to flash message. `names` has 20 items, so the loop runs 20 times.

I want to pass a parameter to the program that's the number of threads Ii need to spawn to do my job. For example, if I pass `4` as the parameter then I will spawn four threads, I can start four threads and it will trigger four tasks and will wait for them to complete their job.

Once one them finishes, it will take the 5th task.  In similar manner it 6th, 7th and 8th and again until there is nothing left:

```
foreach my $MyTest (@names)
{
    unless(TestMe())
    {
        print "$MyTest Failed";
    }
}
```

Comment: See [Thread::Queue](http://p3rl.org/Thread::Queue).

Comment: [Parallel::ForkManager](https://metacpan.org/pod/Parallel::ForkManager) might be useful, but I'm having a hard time understanding what it is exactly that you want to do. Since you seem to have no idea how to start, reading [perlthrtut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlthrtut) might be a good start...

Comment: Thanks choroba and Dada I will have a check

Comment: Sorry that it is bit confusing ..

Comment: Sorry that it is bit confusing ..basically I need to have a pool of threads.
I have 20 task .now the program has to get threads from this pool and use them to perform this 20 task.
For example i will passed a command line parameter to the program say 4 .
The program then have 4 threads and these 4 threads has to run in parallel to finished the 20 task.
At a certain instance it can only do 4 task so if it finishes it will take rest task and completes in batch.

Comment: In short, you have a bunch of jobs and want to work on N at a time.

Comment: Yes i have a bunch of job and want to work n at a time